# Prevent DIV from appearing partially outside of the window

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV popping up at the bottom right of the cursor whenever a user right-clicks on a row in my table. The problem is, if a user right-clicks near the bottom of their browser window, the DIV will pop up  and get cut off where the window ends.

Is there a way to detect if this will happen and if it will, position the DIV above and to the right of my cursor instead?

Forgot to mention!! I'm using [this plugin](http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/). I don't mind if I need to alter the plugin's source a bit.

Comment: Sure there is. What have you tried? Can you post your code?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm using a plugin to do this - see my updates in my question.

Comment: But whats you're code? css, html for the element(s), javascript you've done to make it on you're site. Knowing the plugin is only so helpful. Are you able to provide a jsfiddle.net version of you're code?